# Why is threading is still inconsistent?

Tags: java, multithreading

I have a some java code that simulates bank transfers. The account class simply has a balance field and a transfer method that add some balance to the balance field.

The TransferManager defines a Transfer class which takes two Account objects to transfer a given amount from the one account to the other that are passed as parameters.

The Manager itself has two important methods that need to be synchronized because the both operate on the same resource and they will be called in a threaded way:

```
public synchronized void issueTransfer(Account from, Account to, int amount) {
    openTransfers.add(new Transfer(from, to, amount));
    issuedTransfers++;
}

public synchronized void performTransfers() {
    for(Transfer transaction : openTransfers) {
        transaction.performTransfer();
            performedTransfers++;
    }       
    openTransfers.clear();
}
```

Without the synchronization statement here I get NullPointerExceptions on the  arraylist where Transfers are stored and read.

BankTest spawns 10 threads, each issues 10 transfers. Just have a look at BankTest.java. The problem is that not always 10*10 transfers are issued. Sometimes there are 98 or 99:

[image]

Do I have to add synchronization to BankTest.java? What should I do? Any other ideas or suggestions?

**TransferManager.java**: http://pastebin.com/Je4ExhUz

**BankTest.java**: http://pastebin.com/cdpWhHPb

**Exersice3.java**: http://pastebin.com/v7pwJ5T1

**Account.java**: http://pastebin.com/QYEeWy5Z

Comment: Without which `synchronized` keyword? For issueTransfer or performTransfers?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
try {
    Thread.sleep(60);
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

this does not guarantee that all threads are finished

instead keep all threads in a list and call join on all of them

```
try {
    for(Thread thr:threads)thr.join();
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: thanks that helps, I have 100 transfers now. But there is still a problem, you can see it in the last line of the screenshot, account balance is everywhere 0, can you see why the balance is not applied ?

Comment: @Art - I think it is applied. But `manager.issueTransfer(accounts[index], accounts[(index+1)%accounts.length], 100);` every account gives 100 to the next. In total, everybody gets as much as he gave?

Comment: because the 100 is just shuffled and eventually goes back to where it came from try setting the amount transferred to something variable

Comment: no, sometime every balance is 0 sometimes some are 100 if I do e.g. 1*index I get values like 450 for balance which can't be true. what do you think?

Answer (score 1):

[Race conditions?](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition)

Without synchronizing the openTransfers.add statement, two threads could simultaneously add an object to the openTransfers list. Let's say the list is empty, both threads could add the element to the first position(the second thread overwriting the first) and then both increase the size. This gives you a list of size 2 with 1 object and 1 null pointer.

This is just one of the many incorrect things that could happen. If 10 threads all execute `size = size + 1`, after finishing `size` could be any value between 1 and 10. That might explain why there are sometimes 99 transfers. That `size` is 99, now does not mean there are 99 items, there could be 100 elements in the list, or 98, or just 1.

You really should try to synchronize everything where multiple threads can write the same data. But be careful not to deadlock.