# Deadlock problem with bank situation

Tags: c#, multithreading

I have a problem, i cannot resolve this problem

```
void Transfer(Account a, Account b, decimal amount) 
{
       lock (a) {
             lock (b) {
                         if (a.Balance < amount)
                         throw new InsufficientFundsExc();
                         a.Balance -= amount;
                         b.Balance += amount;
                         }
                   }
}
```

and question is " this is a transfer between bank accounts. "lock(...)" structure is used against race condition.  What is this problem? and what solution do you propose? CAN YOU HELP ME?

Comment: My question is, "is this homework?"

Comment: What have you considered and where are you getting stuck?  Can you supply data on your attempts to solve it?

Comment: I added the homework tag.  @user744303: Please remove that tag if this isn't homework

Comment: Why are you multithreading this in the first place? In my experience multithreading expensive calculation is sometimes useful, but multithreading the whole domain is usually a bad idea.

Comment: Reminds me of this [bank threading question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5928432/why-is-threading-is-still-inconsistent)

Comment: Why does this belong to c#, java, c and vb?

Answer (score 10):

if you have a transfer from A to B at the same time as a transfer from B to A it can deadlock because you have no lock order.

- Thread 1 locks A
- Thread 2 locks B
- Thread 1 waits on B
- Thread 2 waits on A
- dead

But why the hell is this code multithreaded in the first place?

You need to take your locks always in the same order. For example by giving each lock an integer Id and always locking the lower ID first.

Comment: Please can you explain this in more detail and can you advise me in how to solve this

Comment: Take your locks always in the same order. Or just drop multithreading alltogether. This doesn't look like a situation where multithreading is necessary in the first place.

Comment: Plus it is usually bad practice or at least error prone (and often a sign of a weak design) to take locks on resources you don't completely own and encapsulate.  In this example, the `Transfer` method exhibits this problem because it is hard to implement without locking two resources that don't logically have the same owner.

Comment: Is this the right solution?void Transfer(Account a, Account b, decimal amount) 
{
       lock (a) {
             lock (b) {
                         if (a.Balance < amount)
                         throw new InsufficientFundsExc();
                         
                         b.Balance += amount;
                         }
                  a.Balance -= amount; }
}

Comment: No, that's no better than the original. You still have no lock order.

Comment: i don't know how to resolve, i think i had lock order because i use (a,b) and then (b,a) ???

Comment: As I already said: "You need to take your locks always in the same order. For example by giving each lock an integer Id and always locking the lower ID first." But IMO the right solution is avoiding multithreading in this situation.

Comment: make solution for this problem, i dont know what are you talking about?

Comment: give me code example with "locking integer ID and locking the lower ID first" please?

Comment: If it's homework do it yourself. If it's no homework but a real problem throw out the multithreading. I won't do your homework for you.

Comment: it's not homework, i'm really new in stackoverflow.com and someone else tag this problem as homework ? HELP

Comment: Then you should either learn a lot about multithreading or don't use it at all. Multithreading is hard, it's easy to make mistakes which randomly occur, and it is rarely necessary. I recommend selectively using multithreading on expensive calculations.

Comment: DO YOU KNOW SOLUTION OF THIS PROBLEM? HELPPPP

Comment: you didn't properly specify your Account class or your programming language (is it c#, c++ or java?), because of that it's quite hard to give you a working solution, but conceptually CodeInChaos has given you a sufficient answer.(posting in all-caps isn't going to get you more attention)

Comment: problem is in the c# and the code is : class Account {
  double balance;
  int id;

  void withdraw(double amount){
     balance -= amount;
  } 

  void deposit(double amount){
     balance += amount;
  } 

   void transfer(Account a, Account b, double amount){
        if(a.withdraw <amount)
          {
  a.withdraw;
             b.deposit;
             
           }
    }

}

Comment: I won't give you a complete answer. Because if you can't solve this easy problem you should not use this kind of multithreading in the first place. I avoid this kind of multithreading myself since it's so easy to make a mistake and get indeterministic memory corruption or deadlocks. If you want to you should really read several articles about locking, lock order etc.

Comment: if you had know answer you would posted that and you would not talking so much about how difficult is this problem. If you know post that, to see how you can solve easy problems.

Comment: I don't believe that you can solve this problem CodelnChaos :)

Comment: You just introduce a unique integer field into your account class. You can do that using `Interlocked.Increment`. And then sort the locks you want to take by that id.

Comment: give me a exampleee, you can tell me all the day "take by id" but i don't understand  I wanna to see how can i do this with code, give me example?

Comment: is there anybody that can solve this problem i need it for tommorow?

Comment: is this solution for problem with semaphores ?

Comment: is this solution? mutex=1;

void wait(s) { while(s<=0); s--; }

void signal(s) { s++; }

void Transfer(Account a, Account b, decimal amount) { wait(mutex); lock (a) { lock (b) { if (a.Balance < amount) throw new InsufficientFundsExc(); a.Balance -= amount; b.Balance += amount; } } signal(mutex); }

Comment: CodelnChaos i needed it for my web application, and i'm not child as you to do homework ahahhahahahhaa

Comment: Can you help me to create PHP forum with Mysql, because i cannot make question i don;t know why

Answer (score 4):

If you can order the accounts (by ID number or something), you can always lock the one with the lower ID first. This will ensure that no thread tries to lock `a` then `b` at the same time as another thread locking `a` then `b`, as they will both lock `a` first.

Answer (score 3):

deadlock

when Transfer(a,b,10.0); and Transfer(b,a,10.0); are called simultaneously 
the first call will lock a 
then the second can lock b before the first can lock a 
and neither can continue -> deadlock

Answer (score 0):

As CodeInChaos suggests, your problem is a potential deadlock. If you don't understand what a deadlock is then I recommend reading the [dining philosophers problem on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dining_philosophers_problem).

The article explains the problem in real terms and suggests some solutions including using a [locking order](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dining_philosophers_problem#Resource_hierarchy_solution).

Edit:
To further relate your problem to the article, the bank accounts are forks (i.e. shared resources that can only be used exclusively therefore need to be locked) and the threads accessing the code are the philosophers (i.e. entities that from time to time require the use of lockable resources).

Answer (score 0):

@RatchetFreak hit the nail on the head with his response regarding why this has occured. I think the main problem that you are having it that a lock is a very low level construct which makes it difficult to think about threading scenario's sanely.

I would recommend (if possible) to use a set of slightly higher level constructs to make life easier on yourself. Daniel Chamber's has a good light weight set of utilities for this in [his library](http://dcutilities.codeplex.com/).

Answer (score 0):

Imagine two very stubborn ladies went to a holiday house with their husbands.  They woke the next morning and found the men gone.  The only clothes left: a skirt and a shirt (seems one of the men liked wearing women's clothing - could explain a lot).  The ladies realise the need to go get stuff - food, clothes, new husbands.  They both think "well, I'll put the clothes on and go", and one puts on the skirt while the other dons the shirt.  They see what's happened but each is too stubborn to change their plan (and way too shy to go out half naked).  Their stubbornness is akin to a dumb computer following a program that "looked good at the time".  They can't/won't automatically revise the seemingly sensible approach they had above on hitting a "run-time error", so they are both doomed to starve to death.  That's a *dead lock*: waiting for resources you can't get because someone's waiting for what you're hogging yourself.

With a bit more foresight and planning, they could have found a strategy that would make sure one of them got out.  For example:

- order based on the objects being sought:

  - e.g. only when you've already got the skirt can you take the shirt (at least with locks, one of two threads contesting it is guanteed to get it without ripping it in two), OR
- order based on the would-be owners:

  - if both want to go out at the same time, whoever's birthday is earlier can go first, or if the same then whoever's taller etc, OR
- both strip again and try after a short but random interval

etc.